# Finding a date from string using shell script?

Tags: date

How can I find a date inside a string using *shell script*?
For example, I have this string  "`/foo/bar/mxm-20140908.txt`" 
and the out put should be `20140908`, thanks!

Comment: is your string having always the same structure? e.g. /foo/bar/mxm- and then the date?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `egrep` with the `-o` option. One where it uses a `-` separator (as per the original question):

```
pax> echo /foo/bar/mxm-2014-09-08.txt | egrep -o '[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}'
2014-09-08
```

Or, with no separator (as per the changes made):

```
pax> echo /foo/bar/mxm-20140908.txt | egrep -o '[0-9]{8}'
20140908
```

Just have to be careful in that latter case if the eight digits may show up somewhere in a non-date context.